# SharePoint deployment failure using VS2008 on the comannd line

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, command-line, deployment

I am trying to implement a nightly build environment for our SharePoint solution that includes VS 2008 and VS 2008 extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (version 1.2).
When I deploy via the VS 2008 GUI it works fine. 
When I use the command line:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe SharePoint.sln /Deploy Release
```

I get the following error:

```
------ Deploy started: Project: SharePoint.Site, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
------ Generate solution file and setup batch file ------
Creating solution ...
System.NotImplementedException
Error: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Others seem to be having [similar issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/5241b654-49b1-407f-aa6d-f4a739cc9b3b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSeWSS 1.2 doesn't support command line builds. I would either try the [CTP for VSeWSS 1.3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6&displaylang=en) or a community tool like [STSDev](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/) or [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/).